# Automatic hiding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, mouseover, fadeout

ANOTHER EDIT:

This is the complete code, as a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/pbb9cc9f/7/) the menu is working but I can't implement it into my HTML file. What did I do wrong? Are the preloaded javascript links wrong? Is the cycle slideshow messing with the menu? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>CHRIS RHODES</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slide').cycle({ 
    fx:     'none', 
    timeout:  0, 
    next:   '#nex',
    prev: '#pre' 
});

$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39)
    {        
       $('#slide').cycle('next');
    }

    if (e.keyCode == 37)
    {
        $('#slide').cycle('prev');
    }

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

  var time = 3000,
    timer;

  clearTimeout(timer);
  $('.target').stop(true).css('opacity', 1).show().fadeOut(8000);

  function handlerIn() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $('.target').stop(true).css('opacity', 1).show();
  }

  function handlerOut() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $('.target').fadeOut(8000);
    }, time);
  }

  $(".link, .target").hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);

}());
</script>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 8pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

a {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 8pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

.target {
  display: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 98px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: red;
}

.link {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 138px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: blue;
}

#slide {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

#pre {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: w-resize;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nex {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: e-resize;
  z-index: 999;
}

.Absolute-Center {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}

.Absolute-Center.is-Resizable {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 90%;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

</style>

</head>

<div class="link"></div>

<div class="target">
CHRIS RHODES<br><br>
<a href="http://www.chrisjrhodes.co.uk">Comissions</a><br>
<a href="http://www.chrisjrhodes.co.uk/editorial">Editorial</a><br>
<a href="http://www.chrisjrhodes.co.uk/contact">Contact</a><br>
</div>

<div id="pre"></div>
<div id="nex"></div>

<ul id="slide">
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/01-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/02-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/03-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/04-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/05-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/06-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/07-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/08-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/09-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/10-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/11-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/12-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/13-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/14-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
<img src="http://chrisjrhodes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/15-800x800.jpg" class="Absolute-Center is-Resizable"/>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't do this. Your right, you can't hover an element that isn't there. You nees some kind of element that is always on the page. Also how does the user know where to hover without any kind of visual clue?

Comment: The menu is supposed to be visible when visiting the page, then "turning invisible." People can hover back on it when they want to use it.

Comment: So you want it to be transparent? So not disapear but become "see through"? Given the additional code you've now posted what **exactly** is the question?

Comment: The javascript works on the fiddle but not on my code, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need another visible element as a hover source in this case. It can be something else visible, or just  few pixel wide line you leave on the UI, or some special element/icon that you can create just for this. That should work on desktop or mobile too.

Comment: I don''t think another element will do, I will have to start over with the code so the menu just is invisible. It's very simple, three links in simple html and I don't mind them just being transparent as long as they stay and just come back once I hover over them.

Answer (score 0):

try changing `visibility`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.menu').css("visibility", "hidden");
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

`visibility: hidden` only hides the element from your vision. But it will be there. Not like `display: none;`

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to work, it still disappears I as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

This is the js code of mine which performs what you're discribing. Let me know if you'd like the css and html part, you can play around with it and style it your own.

```
function expand(s){
   var td = s;
   var d = td.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
   td.classname = "menuHover";
   d.className = "menuHover";
}

function collapse(s){
   var td = s;
   var d = td.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
   td.className = "menuNormal";
   d.className = "menuNormal";
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, of how to fire the event if the menu is invisible. I think that's the real problem here.